# Wordpress Multisite FQDN Admin Access

Tags: multisite, admin, nginx, user-access

I have a Wordpress multisite setup at http://in-autos.com and I have a sub-domain multisite structure and a FQDN http://billgattonsales.com

**My trouble:**
I can access the Admin area by visiting either the main site, or any sub-domain, but I cannot access the Admin area using the FQDN.  So FQDN/wp-admin/ will not work.

What am I missing to get the FQDN/wp-admin/ to work correctly?

The DNS is forwarded, and the site works great from the home page, and sub-pages.  Permalinks is working fine.

**Server Setup:**
I'm running the WP Multisite on a VM behind an Nginx router.  Nginx appears to be functioning correctly.

Please tell me what you need.  Thank you.

Access Log:

```
[10/Mar/2016:16:15:14 -0500] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1457644514.5484681129455566406250 HTTP/1.0" 200 20 "-" "WordPress/4.4.2; billgattonsales.in-autos" "-"
[10/Mar/2016:16:15:14 -0500] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "billgattonsales/wp-admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0" "-"
[10/Mar/2016:16:15:14 -0500] "GET /wp-login.php?redirect_to=billgattonsales.in-autos%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1276 "billgattonsales/wp-admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0" "-"
```

After a few seconds, the screen is blank with no error codes.  Error log is empty.

`tail -f error.log` produces no results.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience WP doesn't like being accessed from anywhere that's not the site url in the `wp_config` table.

If you want to change the URL to your new(?) one [this codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) should help, however it will probably prevent you from accessing by your old(?) url.

Comment: Thank you Joshua.  This is a WP multisite setup, and there's only one wp-config file.  Can a second wp-config file be setup just for the sub-domain in a multisite?  After searching, I'm not finding anything.  Or maybe you're saying that I have to define all sub-domains?  If so, how would I do this?